# Find email with subject set in variable and move

Tags: vba, outlook

I'm trying to create a macro that finds an email by the subject line, which is stored in a variable, and then move said email to another folder. What I have done so far is the following:

```
Dim myOlApp As New Outlook.Application
Dim objNamespace As Outlook.Namespace
Dim objFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
Dim strFilter As String

Set objNamespace = myOlApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set MySentItems = objNamespace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderSentMail)
Set SentItems = MySentItems.Items
Set EARInbox = objNamespace.Folders("EAR Inbox")

.
.
.

Subject = Email.Subject

Set Mail = SentItems.Find("[Subject] = " & Subject)

Mail.Move EARInbox.Folders("Sent Items")
```

I've realised that the above works if I write the exact subject line when trying to find, but when using a variable, it always gives me is "Cannot Parse "(" " , or something like that.

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: `Set Mail = SentItems.Find("[Subject] = """ & Subject & """")` need quotes around the subject

Answer (score 1):

Your variable needs quotes since it represents text so try:

```
Set Mail = SentItems.Find("[Subject] = """ & Subject & """")
```

Comment: You also need to replace all `"` with `""` in the subject value